# Executing adb from php

Tags: server, permissions, android, sudo, php

I am trying to run adb from PHP using:

```
exec( 'adb devices', $output, $return_val );
```

but I get 126 error.

I think the problem is that php is running as 'www-data' user and does not have permissions to execute adb.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow the www-data user to run to run *adb* and *abd* with no password:

```
sudo visudo
```

Add to the contents of the sudoers file:

```
User_Alias WWW_USER = www-data
Cmnd_Alias WWW_COMMANDS = /sbin/adb, /sbin/abd
WWW_USER ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: WWW_COMMANDS
```

Save.